# Uniqueness of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, finite-fields

Assume $L$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$. Show there exists a unique finite field of cardinality $p^n$ containing $\mathbb{F}_p$. The existence is easy just have to define the splitting field of $X^{p^n}-X$. But what about uniqueness?

Comment: Well, there are at most $p^n$ solutions in $\overline{\mathbb F}_p$ to the equation $x^{p^n}-x=0$. On the other hand, all the elements of a field of $p^n$ elements must satisfy the equation $x^{p^n}-x=0$. So the elements of such a field are exactly those $p^n$ solutions.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: Why the element of that field with $p^n$ must satisfy the equation? How can I deduce it without mentioning the fact that every finite field has cyclic multiplicative group.

Comment: You don't need it to be cyclic. You just need it to be a group (which it is by definition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Prove that every element of such extension is a root of $x^{p^n} - x$.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative subgroup of nonzero elements of a field with $p^n$ elements is an abelian group of $p^n - 1$ elements; every element is a root of $X^{p^n - 1} - 1$.